# Getting post variables in zend rest controller

Tags: zend-framework, zend-rest

I would like to get `POST` data sent to page controller in `init()` function but what I get is an empty array.

However, getting `getRawBody` displays data.

Here is the command I use:

```
curl http://localhost/api/page/7 -X PUT -d "test=true"
```

and the output is:

> Array 
>       (
>       )
>       test=true

```
class Api_PageController extends Zend_Rest_Controller
{
    public function init()
    {
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
        $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        print_r($this->getRequest()->getRawBody());    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want is the PutHandler plugin. This will make POST and PUT use the same getParams();

put this in your **application.ini**

```
resources.frontController.plugins.putHandler = Zend_Controller_Plugin_PutHandler
```

Then the data should appear when you call

```
$this->getRequest->getParams();
```